# Using a database in .NET

Tags: c#, sql, database

UPDATED QUESTION:

Ok, I am going to simplify my question since I don't really know how to answer your questions.

Say I create a new Windows Forms Application,
then Project->Add New Item->Local Database.

Then in Database Explorer I create a table ("testtable") and give it an "ID" column and "VALUE" column.

Can you provide me with the steps to simply add a row to the database from the code?

OLD QUESTION:

> I have been trying to do something
>   that I think would be really easy but
>   have never used C# before and am
>   having trouble with the details. I
>   simple want to use a sql database with
>   Visual C# Express 2008.
>
> For testing purposes I have a datagrid
>   on my form that can reflect changes to
>   the db.
>
> If i use this:
>
> ```
> codesTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet1.codes);
> ```
>
> The datagrid(dataset) will fill with
>   the info from the sql database.
>
> If i then do something like this:
>
> ```
> codesTableAdapter.InsertQuery(txtCode.Text,txtName.Text);
> codesTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet1.codes);
> codesTableAdapter.Update(dataSet1);
> dataSet1.AcceptChanges();
> ```
>
> The datagrid reflects the changes but
>   if close the program and go to the
>   database the changes are not there.
>   When I open the program again the
>   changes are not there.
>
> I have a feeling this isn't too clear
>   as my understanding here is very low
>   so please let me know what other info
>   is needed.

Comment: How are you connecting to your database? How is the dataset populated?

Comment: Need a bit more information. Where are your changes to the dataset1 being made? It appears to me that you fill your dataset then do an update, but I see no place changes are made.
Also what is .codes?  I don't recall 'codes' being a member of dataset.

Comment: It would seem my problem is much simpler than I thought. I was expecting when debugging that the program would be using the same database each time but I think it replaces it each time? If this is the case is there a setting to keep changes when debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really hard to understand what is going on without seeing your code, but I will make some guesses:

> Say I create a new Windows Forms application then Project->Add New Item->Local Database

This will create an empty SQL Server Compact Edition .SDF file in your project. You can edit this file from Visual Studio or SQL CE Query Analyzer.

> Then in Database Explorer I create a table ("testtable") and give it an "ID" column and "VALUE" column.

This will create an empty table in your .SDF file. Those are pretty bad names, but for test purpose we can use them.

> Can you provide me with the steps to simply add a row to the database from the code?

`System.Data.SqlServerCe` provides methods to manage .SDF files. To add a row to your test table:

```
using (SqlCeConnection myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=Path\To\Your\SDF\file.sdf;"))
using (SqlCeCommand myCmd = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    myCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testtable (ID, [VALUE]) VALUES (1, whatever)";
    myConnection.Open();
    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Be aware that `Path\To\Your\SDF\file.sdf` may not be what your think; Visual Studio by default copies project files to the  Project Build Output Path (e.g. Path\to\your\project\bin\Debug\file.sdf). If you change the built file then rebuild your project, the original .SDF file gets recopied to your output path, wiping out any changes you have made to your project file. If that's not what you want you will have to explain what you are trying to accomplish.

For example, to make changes apply only to the built project file, change your data file "Copy to Output Directory" property in VS to "Copy if Newer".

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem is that you are looking at a different copy of the database than you are inserting into.  Are you using SqlCE?  The database could be copied to the output directory and therefore may be a different DB than the one that you are looking at...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try something like this.

```
DataTable dt = dataSet1.Tables["codes"];
codesTableAdapter.InsertQuery(txtCode.Text,txtName.Text); 
codesTableAdapter.Fill(dt); 
// Add a new row to your datatable;
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["ID"] = 100;
dr["Value"] = "This is my value";  // this is assumeing the 'Value' columns is of type string.
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

codesTableAdapter.Update(dataSet1); 
dataSet1.AcceptChanges();
```